# what is the reason that display flex make <hr> hidden?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/GyWKab

html

```
<p> hr should appear below, but not </p>
<div>
  <hr />
</div>

<p> outside of a flex display, hr shows below correctly
<hr />
```

css

```
div {
  display: flex;
}
hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your Codepen snippet works as expected. The horizontal rule is visible in both the nested <div> and below the <p> tag. Not sure what the problem is you're experiencing.

Comment: @andrewhiles yea, I fixed it myself, few min later after I submitted this question lol